# How to specify the default selected Radiobutton in MFC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have two radiobuttons on my dialog. I set up the tabstop order correctly and turned the group property on on one of them and added an int member variable which I can read.

What I'm wondering now is: How can I preselect a default option? Right now, when the dialog gets created, no radiobutton ist visually selected. Doing m_membervariable = 1; compiles, but it also doesn't select a radiobutton. How can I do that?

I checked tutorials like 
http://www.functionx.com/visualc/controls/radiobutton.htm and
http://www.cpp-tutor.de/mfc/mfc/kap8/lektion2.htm
but they seem to ommit that.

Best regards
    Marc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [CheckRadioButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/102xeb09%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to set the state of the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

[DDX_Radio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fchz3yh5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You should define the range of the available values for your radio buttons in String Table. So if you have two controls, you specify 0 and 1, so the first value for m_membervariable is for your first control and the second one for your second.

Comment: Hmm, maybe that's the point I'm missing. Because I'm not exactly sure what you are suggesting to do. I have no String Table right now. What should I write in there? m_membervariable is an int. How can it have two values? Should I make it an int[2] or something like that?